# Can't convert JSON to String (PHP & Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make connection with a API and i want 
to learn to work with it. (I work with Laravel) 
I am trying to convert a JSON to a
string but if i echo the converted string it gives me this error:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 531:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/stackingcoder/development/PHP/internetstuffer/resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

This is my HomeController.php :

```
public function index()
{
    $url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/WIKI.json';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $string = json_decode($data, true);

    curl_close($ch);

    return view('index', compact('string'));
}
```

I am using templating engine Blade, so my echo looks like this:

```
{{ $string }}
```

Edit:

As end result i just need an array, how do i convert the API call to an array? So in can split the data like this:

```
echo $data['database']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your last line. once you use `json_decode` with `true` flag, it will return array.

```
public function index()
{
    $url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/WIKI.json';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $string = json_decode($data, true);

    curl_close($ch);

    // name can be called here as $string['database']['name'] 

    // once passed the string to view, called inside blade as $database['name']
    // It seems i have to use compact, otherwise it will give me the
    // error: Undifined variable: $string
    return view('index', compact('string'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from your sample what the `view` function is and where it is defined, but in any case you run `compact` on your string, so you are probably feeding some part of your template system an array where it expects a string.

from the [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php): compact -> Create array containing variables and their values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the JSON as a string, when it is returned by cURL, it is already a string. There is no need to use json_decode, which actually turns it into an array (as you it set to true in the 2nd parameter).

Compact function also creates an array, so I've taken that out as well. 
(See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

```
public function index()
{
    $url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/WIKI.json';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);    
    curl_close($ch);

    return view('index', $data);
}
```